# How to hide one environment from the set of users in Octopus deploy

Tags: continuous-integration, octopus-deploy

I have got a playground environment and I would like to hide it from the people in the team for internal testing purposes.

What should I do ?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a "Team" in Octopus Configuration in the web portal, you can assign environments to that team.

This allows you to grant access to a specific list of environments and the others are effectively invisible, for example on the Dashboard, for the users of that "Team" (a team in Octopus is basically a permission group).

Answer (score -1):

Would the [documentation](https://octopus.com/docs/key-concepts/environments#Environments-Environmentpermissions) not be a good start?

In particular [this section](https://octopus.com/docs/administration/managing-users-and-teams#Managingusersandteams-Creatingteams) talks about setting up a team, where one can allow for only specific environments.